# How to handle multiple images with duplicate titles in an image sitemap?

Tags: xml-sitemap, google-image-search, image-search

We got multiple different images for each recipe URL (user-generated content) - therefore, in our image sitemap, there are multiple image URLs with the same title (=recipe title). What are your experiences with indexation of images from image XML sitemaps - did duplicate titles affect indexation negatively?

Comment: As far as I know Google doesn't use image site maps titles for ranking purposes, in fact the title tag within an image site map is completely optional. Google should only care for the alt tag embedded on pages, as I believe Google does not index images without them being embedded on a page somewhere.

Comment: They are embedded, but they are all showing pretty much the same - say, 50 different approaches to Spaghetti Bolognese - which is why they all have the same titles and/or captions. I was just wondering if they might be indexed at all if that happens. I can't for the live of me imagine 50 different titles for Spaghetti Bolognese ;)